# mod_rewrite with %26

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to pass in as a parameter a category name like this

"Lights+&+Lamps"

with this rewrite rule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        example.com$
RewriteRule ^/category/([^/]+)$   /showproduct.pl?category=$1 [PT]
```

I understand & is a paramater separator, but even when I pass in :

"Lights+%26+Lamps"

My output is "Lights"

So mod rewrite is eating everything at %26

I've tried different flags like [NE] and QSA with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is is "Lights" or "Lights " (with space)?

Comment: Can you post the whole resulting querystring or request URL?

Comment: What does your browser display in the addressbar? Did he maybe unescape the `%26` without telling you?

Comment: Looks like in my rewrite log i'm seeing Lights&Lamps when i'm feeding in %26... so %26 is getting converted back into & somehow

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem where the '&'(ampersand) was incorrectly rewritten by the mod_rewrite. The B flag solved it:

> **B (escape backreferences)** The [B] flag instructs RewriteRule to escape
>   non-alphanumeric characters before applying the transformation.

It allowed me to serve the files containing '&' within their name, eg [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b)
What you need is this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        example.com$
RewriteRule ^/category/([^/]+)$   /showproduct.pl?category=$1 [B, PT]
```

Comment: yes, [B] is the gist. I bypassed similar problem by replacing & with ＆

Answer (score 0):

Could you rewrite `%` to `%25` with another rule before that?

Comment: eh i think that might have some unintended consequences on some other urls. Better to force escaping on this one case I think somehow?

Comment: Ok, you're right. Could you do the second escaping client-side?